# VBA Application.OnTime Specify both workbook and macro name and send arguments

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to run Application.OnTime and specify both the workbook and some arguments. I can get them to work on their own, but not together.

For example, the following code works if "MacroToBeCalled" subroutine is in the same workbook where I set Application.OnTime.  It uses single quotes, as explained [here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/vba/xl%20objects%20and%20procedures%20with%20arguments.htm).

```
Application.OnTime Now(), "'MacroToBeCalled ""String To Send""'"
```

Also, the following code works if "MacroToBeCalled" subroutine is in the workbook called "Test File.xlsm", which is different to where I'm running this line of code.

```
Application.OnTime Now(), "'Test File.xlsm'!MacroToBeCalled"
```

However, I can't find a way of sending parameters. I'm looking for something like the following, although this does not work.

```
Application.OnTime Now(), "''Test File.xlsm'!MacroToBeCalled ""String To Send""'"
```

What is the format of the string I need to provide for this to work, if it is possible at all?

If you need more detail, I have two workbooks, say one is called A and one is called B. Both A and B contain a subroutine called `MacroToBeCalled`. I am using a button in workbook A, which uses `Application.Run` to run a macro in workbook B called `SetOnTimeToRunMacro`. What I want is for `SetOnTimeToRunMacro` subroutine in workbook B to call `Application.OnTime` to run the `MacroToBeCalled` in workbook B. However, when the `OnTime` is actually trigged, it's running `MacroToBeCalled` in workbook A instead of B, even though the `OnTime` is set in workbook B. If I remove the parameter and specify the workbook, then it works in workbook B.

Comment: Cross posted here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1026572-application-ontime-specifying-both-workbook-arguments.html

Comment: @cxw, I'm afraid that doesn't answer my question. The link you provided just explains how to do what I've done in my first example, which doesn't specify the workbook name, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: OK, what error message are you getting?  What string are you trying to send?

Comment: Even though I spent an hour or so working on this earlier, I've managed to answer this myself. I'll post the answer shortly in case someone else has the same question.

Comment: The correct format to use is: 
Application.OnTime Now(), "'Test File.xlsm'!'MacroToBeCalled ""String To Send""'"
With single quotes both before and after the ! mark, but not including it.

Comment: Will do, didn't know I could answer my own question!

Comment: You can also delete comments, which I have just done to mine so that future readers aren't tempted to wade through discussion that did not ultimately contribute to the answer.  **Also,** in a few days the system will let you accept the answer you posted.  Would you please, so future readers know it worked for you?  Your solution also worked for me --- I tried it just now.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format to use is:

```
Application.OnTime Now(), "'Test File.xlsm'!'MacroToBeCalled ""String To Send""'"
```

The part before the ! mark, and the part after, should have single quotes.